# The Netstat command equivalent on IOS 15

Tags: cisco-ios-15

I have IOS Version 15.2(4)S4 on my router, and "show control-plane host open-ports" does not work, is there any other command to generate such output? the "show tcp brief" and "show ip sockets" are not that good!

*IOS Version: 7200 Software (C7200-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 15.2(4)S4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)*

Comment: `show tcp-small-servers` and `show udp-small-servers` ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly the same but may help, as it shows the far end peer address. Original command did not. But if you use "bgp listen", you then lose the foreign address! Interesting question for an exam maybe.

```
R5#show tcp brief all
TCB       Local Address               Foreign Address             (state)
6792B388  *.179                       4.4.4.4.*                   LISTEN
```

Answer (score 2):

For UDP you can use

```
Router# show udp
```

and if you want to see detail of a particular socket then

```
Router# show socket <PID> detail
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which router you use, but on IOS 15, I only know the "show control-plane host open-ports" command, so there is no equivalent to that, as far as I know.